# Password managers on usb drives for raspberry pi 3

Tags: usb, filesystem, password

If I use a password manager to store all passwords including my password for the pi itself. Does any type of text file or folder get created and stored anywhere on the raspberrypi..or only on the usb drive?

Comment: Depends on the password manager, and whether it's "portable" or not.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "portable"

Comment: That it does not require installation. Essentially, a standalone binary application.